# Is the positive operator $TT^*-T^*T$ on a finite complex inner product space is a zero operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, positive-semidefinite

Suppose the vector space is a complex finite-dimensional inner product space $V$, and the operator $TT^*-T^*T$ is a positive operator on it. Can this information be sufficient to conclude that $TT^*-T^*T$ is a zero operator on $V$?

I think maybe it can guarantee that $TT^*-T^*T=0 $ (or $T$ is normal),but I can't prove this

Comment: I think I saw someone else ask this same question a few days ago.  Someone gave the hint to calculate the trace of $TT^*-T^*T$, which is a very good hint.

Comment: Emm... I basically know nothing about matrices, since my book is more focused on the linear map instead of matrices. Thus are there other ways to solve this problem by not using traces? But to be honest,  I have worked on this question for 3 days by using knowledge about positive operators, spectral theorem, and so on. The more I work on it, the more I feel like I'm now on the wrong way...

Comment: The result is false on infinite dimensional spaces (consider left shift on $\ell^2$).  So any such proof must only work on a finite number of dimensions.  (Or require some other hypothesis, like that $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt operator.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e_i$, $1 \le i \le n$, be an orthonormal basis for $V$.  Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n {\|T e_i\|}^2_2$ is the sum of the squares of the absolute values of the entries of the matrix representing $T$.  Thus
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n {\|T e_i\|}^2_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n {\|T^* e_i\|}^2_2 .$$
Now, if $TT^* - T^*T$ is a positive operator, this means that ${\|T^*x\|}_2^2 - {\|Tx\|}_2^2 \ge 0$ for all $x$.  Thus ${\|T^*e_i\|}_2 = {\|Te_i\|}_2$ for all $1 \le i \le n$.  Since $e_1$ is an arbitrary norm one vector, from this we can see that ${\|T^* x\|}_2 = {\|T x\|}_2$ for every $x \in V$.

Thus $S = TT^* - T^*T$ satisfies $\langle x, S x \rangle = 0$, and if $S$ is a positive operator, this implies $S = 0$.

This is essentially the same proof as using the trace, but unwrapped so that trace is never explicitly mentioned.

Comment: You say "Since $e_1$ is an $\textit{arbitrary}$ norm one vector". Far as I can see, the implication follows from the fact that the collection $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ are of the special orthogonal sort?

Comment: @undefined I must admit I don't see it.  After all, we don't know that the $\{Te_i\}$ are orthogonal.

Comment: @ Stephen Oh yes, you are correct. Never mind. And nice proof by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Here are just some variants of Stephen's answer in the matrix form (just for references by other readers):

In terms of matrices, we know that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ for every two $n\times n$ complex matrices. In particular, we always have $\operatorname{tr}(A^*A)=\operatorname{tr}(AA^*)$, which gives $\operatorname{tr}(A^*A-AA^*)=0$.

If $A^*A-AA^*$ is positive semi-definite, then its eigenvalues are non-negative whence $\operatorname{tr}(A^*A-AA^*)\ge0$. Now the inequality is attained, which means that all the eigenvalues of $A^*A-AA^*$ should be **zero**!

Of course we cannot conclude that a matrix is zero if all of its eigenvalues are zero, but note that $A^*A-AA^*$ is Hermitian whence a normal matrix. It means that $A^*A-AA^*$ is unitarily similar to the zero matrix, hence $A^*A-AA^*=\mathbf{0}$ and
$A^*A=AA^*$, i.e., $A$ is normal.