Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, Problem 7.A.19
I'm trying to solve the following problem (from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", 4th Edition, problem 19 of section 7A) where $T$ is an operator on the finite-dimensional inner product space $V$ and $T^{*}$ is its adjoint:

Suppose $T \in \mathscr L(V)$ and $||T^{*}v||\leq ||Tv||$ for every $v \in V$. Prove that $T$ is normal.

Now this question has already been posted here which unfortunately got closed, but the answer given makes use of traces and the referenced post mentions positive operators neither of which are discussed at this point in Axler's book. However I'm guessing Axler meant for the following theorem (7.16) in the same section as this problem to be used in the proof:

Suppose $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on $V$. Then
$$ \langle Tv,v\rangle =0 \text{ for every } v \in V \iff T=0 $$

I know that $T^{*}T-TT^{*}$ is a self-adjoint operator and that $\langle(T^{*}T-TT^{*})v,v\rangle \geq 0$ for all $v\in V$. If I could prove that $\langle(T^{*}T-TT^{*})v,v\rangle \leq 0$ for all $v\in V$ as well then by the above theorem the problem is solved, however my attempts to do this have failed. So any help on completing this proof or any other proof that does not rely on traces or positive operators is appreciated.
EDIT:
The accepted answer here does match the requirements, I was quick to conclusion because it mentioned "positive operator". Here's the refined version of it:
Problem 7.A.5 in this section asks to prove $\sum_{k}||Te_k||^2=\sum_{k}||T^{*}f_k||^2$ for a linear map $T \in \mathscr L(V, W)$ where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ and $f_1,\dots,f_m$ are orthonormal bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively. Combined with the hypothesis we have $||Te_k||=||T^{*}e_k||$ for all $1\leq k \leq n$ and since $e_1$ was arbitrary we have $||Tv||=||T^{*}v||$ for all $v\in V$ which is an equivalent condition for being a normal operator.

I think the accepted answer on this question only uses material from Section 7A and earlier. No properties of positive operators from Section 7C are really used here; to say that $T T^* - T^* T$ is a positive operator is just to say that $||T^* v|| \leq ||T v||$ for each $v \in V$, which is given in the exercise.

Sorry, that should say "$T^{} T - T T^{}$ is a positive operator".

@terran Thank you. I've checked the answer in that post and indeed it answers this question. I had stumbled upon it myself but dismissed it as soon as I saw it mention positive operator.

@terran By the way I saw you posted a question on problem 6.B.16 (3rd edition) many months ago, here's Axler's own solution to the problem in case you haven't seen it already: here

This question is similar to: Prove $T$ is normal if $| T^*v | \le | Tv |$ for every $v$. It has been elaborated in the comments here so far.

@Pouya Thanks, I hadn't seen that.

@Mike That answer makes use of the trace, which OP wants to avoid.

@Daniel It's not a duplicate because OP is asking for a specific approach that is not available in the previous answers

@DanielSchepler That's a very neat approach, I wish I had thought of it

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387214/is-the-positive-operator-tt-tt-on-a-finite-complex-inner-product-space-is

Here is an outline of a possible proof.  First, for the motivation: choose an eigenvector $v$ of $T$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and then normalize $v$ and extend to an orthonormal basis of $V$.  Then the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis has first column of the form $(\lambda, 0, \ldots, 0)^T$.  On the other hand, $T^* v$ has coordinates of the form $(\bar\lambda, *, \ldots, *)$.  But then, in order to have $\lVert T^* v \rVert \le \lVert Tv \rVert$, that forces all the entries other than the first to be 0.  Thus, the first row of the matrix of $T$ must also be $(\lambda, 0, \ldots, 0)$.
Now, if you trace through this argument and make it coordinate-free, what you end up with is the following argument:
Note that $\langle v, T^* v \rangle = \langle Tv, v \rangle = \bar\lambda \lVert v \rVert^2 = \langle v, \bar\lambda v \rangle$.  Therefore, $v \perp T^*v - \bar\lambda v$, so $\lVert T^* v \rVert^2 = |\lambda|^2 \lVert v \rVert^2 + \lVert T^* v - \bar\lambda v \rVert^2 = \lVert T v \rVert^2 + \lVert T^* v - \bar\lambda v \rVert^2$.  Thus, the hypothesis $\lVert T^* v \rVert \le \lVert Tv \rVert$ forces $T^*v - \bar\lambda v = 0$.
I will now leave it as an exercise to show that $Tv = \lambda v$ and $T^* v = \bar\lambda v$ implies that $\{ v \}^\perp$ is both $T$-invariant and $T^*$-invariant.
From here, the overall argument is one by induction on $\dim V$.  If $\dim V = 1$, then clearly $T$ is normal.  Otherwise, from the previous argument, we can choose an eigenvector $v$, and conclude from the inductive hypothesis that $T$ restricted to $\{ v \}^\perp$ is normal.  (Here, you might need to do an exercise that states that if a subspace $W$ is both $T$-invariant and $T^*$-invariant, then $(T |_W)^* = (T^*) |_W$.)  From here, another exercise will allow you to conclude that $T$ is normal (hint: any element of $V$ can be written as $cv + w$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $w \in \{ v \}^\perp$).

Here is an outline of a proof.  Note: this proof makes use of the spectral theorem, which is apparently beyond the scope of the textbook before this point
First of all, we note that in the case that $T^*T = 0$, we are done since this implies that $\langle T^*Tv, v \rangle = \|Tv\|^2 = 0$, which means that $T = 0$ so that $T$ is necessarily normal.
If $T$ is not zero, we can apply a proof by induction of sorts. Let $n = \dim V$. The case of $n = 1$ is trivial since every operator on a 1-dimensional inner product space is normal. Note that $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ have non-negative eigenvalues. Indeed, if $T^*Tv = \lambda v$, then $\lambda \|v\|^2 = \langle v, T^*Tv \rangle = \|Tv\|^2 \geq 0$. Note also that $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues. Indeed, if $T^*Tv = \lambda v$ with $\lambda \neq 0$, it follows that
$$
TT^*(Tv) = T(T^*T v) = T(\lambda v) = \lambda Tv.
$$
Now, consider the greatest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T^*T$. Note/show that for a unit vector $v$, the maximum possible value of $\langle v, T^*Tv \rangle$ is $\lambda$, and this value will occur if and only if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^*T$ associated with $\lambda$. Now, let $w$ denote an eigenvector of $TT^*$ associated with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$. We have
$$
\lambda = \|TT^*w\|^2 \leq \|T^*Tw\|^2 = \langle w, T^*Tw \rangle.
$$
It follows that $w$ must be an eigenvector of $T^*T$ associated with $\lambda$. Thus, $\text{span}\{w\}$ and $\text{span}\{w\}^\perp$ are invariant subspaces of both $T^*T$ and $TT^*$. It is clear that $T^*T = TT^*$ over $\text{span}\{w\}$; it suffices to show that $TT^*$ and $T^*T$ are equal over the dimension-$(n-1)$ subspace $\text{span}\{w\}^\perp$.
Perhaps you can put the pieces together from there.

Thank you for your detailed answer. I could not figure out the following: 1) $TT^{*}$ having an eigenvalue. at this point I only know complex operators are guaranteed to have eigenvalues. 2) $||Tv||^{2}\leq \lambda$ for the unitary vector.

@Pouya Are we not able to make use of the spectral theorem here? That $TT^*$ is self-adjoint and therefore is unitarily diagonalizable? If not, it's easy to show that any (potentially complex) eigenvalue that a self-adjoint operator $A$ has must be real. Indeed, if $A$ is self-adjoint and $Av = \lambda v$, then
$$
\lambda|v|^2 = \langle Av,v \rangle = \langle v, A^*v \rangle = \langle v, Av \rangle
= \bar \lambda |v|^2.
$$

@Pouya Unfortunately, the fact that $|Tv|^2 \leq \lambda$ does require the spectral theorem, at least as far as the usual proof of this is concerned.

@Pouya Actually, the result regarding eigenvalues being real seems to be given as 7.13, at least in my older edition of the textbook

@Pouya By any chance, is there an earlier exercise in the set that talks about maximizing $\langle Av, v \rangle$ over unit vectors $v$, where $A$ is self-adjoint?

Unfortunately the spectral theorem is in the section just after this. The link terran has provided in the comments answers this question. I was too hasty to dismiss the answer because it mentioned positive operator. The answer uses the fact proved in problem 7.A.5(4th ed.): $\sum_{k}||Te_{k}||=\sum_{k}||T^{}f_{k}||$, combined with the hypothesis we have $||Te_{k}||=||T^{}e_{k}||$ and since $e_1$ is arbitary we have $Tv=T^{*}v$ for all $v$ hence $T$ is normal.

sorry it should say $||Tv||=||T^{}v||$ and $\sum_{k}||Te_k||^2=\sum_{k}||T^{}f_k||^2$
